# My ProgressDialog box does not show when using global variable

Tags: android

**UPDATE 1**

when i ran my app and in the logcat i see the log message which is `cache` and 'nochache' message so it does going whenever i load the activity.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        String xmlList = null;
        xmlList = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
        if(xmlList == null || xmlList.length() == 0)  
        {
             //do so magic here...
             Log.d("xmlList", "nocache"); 

        }
       Log.d("xmlList", "cache");
       return xmlList 
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

okay it does show (progress dialog) only when its not reading from global variable otherwise it gives me a blank black screen and load my activity.... but how can i show the progress dialog all the time?

**end update**

so i have added a global variable to speed-up my xml loading from net and its working as expected but i dont see my dialog box that use to appear.. any idea what its not showing?

below is my code:

here is how it defined global application variable

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private String someVariable;

    public String getSomeVariable() {
        return someVariable;
    }

    public void setSomeVariable(String someVariable) {
        this.someVariable = someVariable;
    }
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
{
    String xmlList = null;
    xmlList = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
    if(xmlList == null || xmlList.length() == 0)  
    {
         //do so magic here...

        }
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() { 
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Player_Activity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage(Player_Activity.this.getString(R.string.loading_msg_dialog));
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: maybe, it is that you have modified your code to post here ... I have some questions, why is that there are two different activities? to create a progressdialog(Media_Player_Activity) and to set a message(Player_Activity). and I don't see you use the global variable you show here except `((MyApplication) getApplication()).getSurahListVariable();`

Comment: it was a typo when i was typing...i have updated my question.

Comment: I am assuming u r dismissing the dialog in PostExecute(). Can you check if the AsyncTask is being called at all. Since your variable is now global, something tells me that the magic doesn't happen after the first run. Tried using Log messages?

Comment: i put some break points on all three `doInBackground,onPostExecute onPreExecute` and it does going on those methods but no dialog box display when i load the activity second time.

Comment: so you see nocache in log. when do you initialize your global variable? how about `Log.d("xmlList", "nocache "+xmlList); ` ?

Comment: thats correct, i see nocache log message when it loads the activity very first time and when i load the activity second time it does from cache with no progressdialogbox, when i do `Log.d("xmlList", "nocache "+xmlList);` i see the entire data in the log

Comment: Just a few clarifications. Your AsyncTask is inside Player_Activity?

Comment: Try one of the Static methods of the ProgressDialog. Though it amuses me as to what relation is there between your progresdialog and Application.
BTW, have you added this to your application in the AndroidManifest?
android:name="com.yourlocationofMyApplication.MyApplication"?

Comment: how would i do the Static method of the ProgressDialog? yes i do have the myapplication in the AnroidManifest.

Comment: ProgressDialog.show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable)